# failed to calculate upgrade

Tags: upgrade

so I tried to update my ubuntu(saucy) to the new LTS release, but it gave me the error that the package manager could not calculate the upgrade.

at which point I ran this in console and got this outcome:

```
 grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log 
Broken libqt5core5a:amd64 Breaks on libqt5core5 [ amd64 ] < 5.0.2+dfsg1-7ubuntu11.1 > ( libs ) (< 5.2.0+dfsg~)
Broken cups-filters:amd64 Conflicts on foomatic-filters [ amd64 ] < 4.0.17-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/text )
Broken libharfbuzz0b:amd64 Conflicts on libharfbuzz0a [ amd64 ] < 0.9.19-1 > ( libs )
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:amd64 Breaks on libcogl12 [ amd64 ] < 1.14.0-2 > ( libs )
Broken unity-control-center:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-control-center-unity [ amd64 ] < 1.3+13.10.20131004-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken libgoa-1.0-0b:amd64 Conflicts on libgoa-1.0-0 [ amd64 ] < 3.8.3-2 > ( libs )
Broken unity-control-center-signon:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-control-center-signon [ amd64 ] < 0.1.7~+13.10.20130724.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken evolution-data-server:amd64 Conflicts on evolution-data-server-goa [ amd64 ] < 3.8.5-1ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (< 3.10.3-0ubuntu2~)
Broken libunity-core-6.0-9:amd64 Conflicts on libunity-core-6.0-8 [ amd64 ] < 7.1.2+13.10.20131014.1-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libunity-core-6.0-9:amd64 Conflicts on unity-common [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken icu-devtools:amd64 Breaks on icu-tools [ amd64 ] < 4.8.1.1-12ubuntu2 > ( libdevel ) (< 52.1-3~)
Broken icu-devtools:amd64 Breaks on icu-tools [ i386 ] < none > ( none ) (< 52.1-3~)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libcogl-pango12:amd64 Depends on libcogl12 [ amd64 ] < 1.14.0-2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.13.4)
Broken libgd-gd2-perl:amd64 Conflicts on libgd-gd2-noxpm-perl [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:2.46-2.1build1 > ( universe/perl )
Broken gnome-control-center-datetime:amd64 Depends on indicator-datetime [ amd64 ] < 13.10.0+13.10.20131023.2-0ubuntu1 -> 13.10.0+14.04.20140415.3-0ubuntu1 > ( misc ) (= 13.10.0+13.10.20131023.2-0ubuntu1)
Broken libghc-comonads-fd-dev:amd64 Depends on libghc-comonad-dev-3.0.1.1-45093 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libperl5.14:amd64 Depends on perl-base [ amd64 ] < 5.14.2-21build1 -> 5.18.2-2ubuntu1 > ( perl ) (= 5.14.2-21build1)
Broken libghc-comonads-fd-prof:amd64 Depends on libghc-comonads-fd-dev [ amd64 ] < 3.0.1-2build2 > ( haskell ) (= 3.0.1-2build2)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140420.48d3dbc8-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140420.08e71e18-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140420.48d3dbc8-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140420.08e71e18-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140420.48d3dbc8-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140420.48d3dbc8-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140420.08e71e18-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140420.48d3dbc8-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140420.08e71e18-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl [ amd64 ] < 0.6.0+git20140313.a4fbc773-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-radeon [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140420.48d3dbc8-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-15 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-15 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140420.48d3dbc8-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140420.08e71e18-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
```

Could anyone please advise me on what to do next?

thx in advance

Comment: yes i've seen that post, but my list of broken packages seems to be quite long and has alot of dependancies, So im not quite sure if its ok to remove ALL of them?? seems to be alot of effort. + its doesnt quite make sense to me because my system runs and updates smoothly otherwise..

Comment: Make sure all your PPAs are disabled by opening the Software Updater and clicking 'Settings...' in the bottom-left and finding the relevant tab. If that doesn't work, report a bug with `ubuntu-bug update-manager-core` and then make a new Ubuntu 14.04 boot CD/USB and select the option to upgrade 13.10 to 14.04.